# C# How is the CancellationToken used with SqlConnection.OpenAsync(token)?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm attempting to use the CancellationToken with SqlConnection.OpenAsync() to limit the amount of time that the OpenAsync function takes.

I create a new CancellationToken and set it to cancel after say 200 milliseconds. I then pass it to OpenAsync(token). However this function still can take a few seconds to run.

Looking at the documentation I cant really see what I'm doing wrong.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync?view=netframework-4.7.2

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    private async void btnTestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString);
        Task.Run(() => QuickConnectionTest(connection)).Wait();
    }

    public async Task QuickConnectionTest(SqlConnection connection)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = source.Token;
        source.CancelAfter(200);

        ConnectionOK = false;

        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync(token);

                if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    ConnectionOK = true;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

I was expecting OpenAsync() to end early when the CancellationToken to throw a OperationCanceledException when 200ms had passed but it just waits.

To replicate this I do the following:

Run the code: Result = Connection OK

Stop the SQL Service

Run the code: hangs for the length of connection.Timeout

Comment: Aren't you missing an `await` before `OpenAsync`?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,1383

Comment: You are right @Nick, there should be a await. I seem to have left this out when I wrote this out, I do however have this in my source code and it still hangs in OpenAsync() when the connection is lost.

Comment: Can you just have your real code?

Comment: I've updated my post with the actual code.

Comment: `SqlConnection` already has a timeout mechanism built into it. The default is 15 seconds, the recommendation when working with Azure is 30 seconds. Which makes setting a sub-second timeout seem somewhat unrealistic anyway.

Comment: @tfcmad what are you trying to do? As Damien explained a connection timeout already exists. Setting a global variable like `ConnectionOK` though just begs for race conditions. If connection fails your method should through unless it can *actually handle reconnection*.

Comment: @tfcmad more problems. `Task.Run` fires a *asynchronous operation* in the background and never awaits it. The click handler will return immediatelly, propbably before execution reaches `await OpenAsync`. Remove `Task.Run` completely and use `await QuickConnectionTest();` instead

Comment: Apologises if my post is unclear. I'm trying to have a timeout of less than 1 second in the worst case of the database not being found. The Connection.Timeout does not allow for less than 1 second, when testing I was finding that testing the connection could take 10 - 40 milliseconds (On the local PC).

Comment: Would the .Wait() on the end of Task.run not allow for this thread to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. If this does not perform cancellation as expected then `SqlConnection.OpenAsync` does not support reliable cancellation. Cancellation is cooperative. If it's not properly supported, or if there is a bug, then you have no guarantees.

Try upgrading to the latest .NET Framework version. You can also try .NET Core which seems to lead the .NET Framework. I follow the GitHub repositories and have seen multiple ADO.NET bugs related to async.

You can try calling `SqlConnection.Dispose()` after the timeout passes. Maybe that works. You also can try using the synchronous API (`Open`). Maybe that uses a different code path. I believe it does not, but it is worth a try.

In case that does not work either you need to write your code so that your logic proceeds even if the connection task has not completed. Pretend that it has completed and let it linger in the background until it completes by itself. This can cause increased resource usage but it might be fine.

In any case consider opening an issue in the GitHub corefx repository with a minimal repro (like 5 lines connecting to example.com). This should just work.

Answer (score 0):

The `CancelationToken` works the same for everyone else that it does for you in your own code.
Example:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("main");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = SomethingAsync(cts.Token);
        cts.Cancel();
        await task;
        Console.WriteLine("Complete");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task SomethingAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000); //didn't pass token here because we want to simulate some work.
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
    }
}

//**Outputs:**
//main
//Started
//… then ~2 seconds later <- this isn't output
//Canceled
//Complete
```

The `OpenAsync` method may require some optimization but don't expect a call to `Cancel()` to immediately cancel any `Task`.  It's just a marshalled flag to let the unit of work within the `Task` know that the caller wants to cancel it.  The work inside the `Task` gets to choose how and when to cancel. If it's busy when you set that flag then you just have to wait and trust the `Task` is doing what it needs to do to wrap things up.

Comment: All of what you say is true, but how does this solve his problem? He requires quick cancellation.

Comment: He needs to cancel and forget.  He can't force it to stop faster than it's going to stop.